# send string message from PC to android using Mac address

Tags: java, c#, android, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

### How to send string message from PC to Android using MAC Address

I have been assigned to create push notification sent from PC to android. The place that I got to use application have many router and have internet. I don't want to use something like GCM but I want to send string message to android directly via internet.

---

So, I want to ask

1. is it possible if I want to send string message from PC to android via internet by using MAC address directly. Using MAC Address to be a destination to tell PC that which android device that should be sent string message.
2. Can I use MAC address to find out IP address and send string message via Internet(if yes, how?)
3. any suggestion?

Thank you :)

Comment: That's a little like sending someone a letter based on their social security number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's so many things wrong with this I don't even know where to begin.

You can't just "send" something over a network. First, a network means nothing more than devices that have the *potential* to communicate with each other. What drives the network is protocols. Protocols can be simplistically thought of as a *language*. It defines the rules and methods for how communication occurs. If I only speak English and you only speak Spanish, we can't communicate, but if I learn Spanish, then we can communicate.

A network works similarly. In order for two devices on a network to communicate they must share similar protocols, but that only gets you half way there. Different protocols are used for different types of communication. So, network communication depends both on the type of message and the ability of devices to understand that type of message.

So, when you say something like "I want to send a push notification", what exactly does that *mean*? Do you want an email, a text message, an request for a REST API endpoint, etc. The possibilities are nearly endless. If you're talking about a "push notification" in the sense of the modern, Apple-popularized popup notification on a mobile device, that's typically done by requesting an API endpoint, but even that is no small thing. It takes initial work of setting up certificates and registering them with Apple, Google, etc. Then, you must use these to authenticate yourself with the appropriate push notification service, and finally send the notification, which then fires off a ton of stuff upstream to determine the ready-state of recipient devices, queuing in case devices are not available, etc.

And, if you *aren't* talking about using the actual push notification service from, in this case, Google, then you're talking about rolling your own, and OMG. The sheer amount of programming and infrastructure to accomplish that, especially on your own, is mind-boggling. Actually mind-boggling doesn't do it justice.

Now, all that is just *the message*. You're also talking about trying to reach a device via it's MAC address, which is virtually impossible. MAC addresses are not and were never intended to be locators; they're *identifiers*. A router will use this identifier potentially to assign an IP address (a locator). The IP address is what you communicate with (at least for IP devices... remember, IP is just another protocol). The only way to get the IP of a device based on the MAC address would have to be some API that the router exposed for that purpose. I'm unaware of any such thing, if it exists.

Long and short, whoever "assigned" this to you doesn't know their hindquarters from a hot rock -- they're idiots. You might as well have been assigned to pick up a taco from Mars.

Comment: You might as well have been assigned to pick up a taco from Mars.